# Maven project keep refreshing / building

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I just encountered issue with Maven used in Eclipse. After checkout Java project as Maven from SVN it keep building and refreshing itself.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution
1. Check in Maven preferences that there is right setting file defined, as I have setting file separate from Maven installation setting file which contain proxy information.

2. Disable the Eclipse "Build Automatically" under Project tab. This might be conflicting with Eclipse and Maven refresh/build.

After these two things, continues refresh of Maven project stopped.